# Providing services for "free"?

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

If I owned and operated a wedding officiating service or any service (photography, etc.), but the way I structure my business is that I do not charge money for officiating weddings, I only require that my transportation, lodging, and food be provided. How do I report that on my taxes? Or, if I was reimbursed for the expenses I spent on the wedding, and I net $0 because those are business expenses, would I owe income tax?

Comment: You are able to deduct expenses related to your self-employment earnings to reduce your taxable income from those earnings. You must report both the gross revenue and the gross expenses, leading to your net income earned number. Be sure that the expenses you claim are actually related to your business, however.

Comment: if you provide it as "service" you wont do it for free. If you do it in private dont mention it at all, otherwise you wont do it for free. Btw it doesn't works out to work for free and just let them pay your expanses, its still income in view of taxes

Comment: The latter case is clear, all income offset by expenses results in no income tax burden, the former case is actually more interesting, it seems like it should be the same as the latter, but IRS rules about bartering almost make it sound like it'd be counted as income and you'd have no expense to offset it with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your net profit is $0, then no, you will not owe income tax as a result of providing this service. But there's a lot more to consider than just that...

Before you begin you'll need to decide if this is a [business or a hobby](https://www.irs.gov/uac/business-or-hobby-answer-has-implications-for-deductions). Based on the fact that you don't intend to make a profit, you are probably going to be calling it a hobby for tax purposes.

Regardless of whether it is a business or a hobby, since you will be accepting payments from people, you will need to report the income on your tax return. As both a business and a hobby you can deduct all of your expenses to bring your profit down to $0. (Assuming all the expenses are legitimate business/hobby expenses.)

The main differences between business and hobby are:

1. If it's a business, you can take a loss and reduce your overall personal tax burden. With a hobby you cannot take a loss even if you have one.
2. If it's a hobby you *must* itemize to deduct expenses. If you are taking the standard deduction you cannot. (With a business you file Schedule C which is compatible with both itemizing and the standard deduction.)
3. If it's a hobby, you can only deduct expenses that [exceed 2% of your AGI](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p529/ar02.html) for the tax year. For example, if your AGI (adjusted gross income) is $50K, than the first $1,000 in hobby expenses are not deductible.
4. If it's a business, and you take a loss too many years in a row, the IRS may choose to reclassify it as a hobby instead.

If you choose to run as a business you'll likely save quite a bit of money by avoiding the 2% rule, and also by being able to deduct any non-specific-customer expenses and take a loss. Be careful though that you don't go too many years with a business loss or the IRS may re-classify it as a hobby, which may include an audit. If you decide to run as a business you may need to charge a little more than just expenses to attempt to turn a profit, or at least break even.

Comment: I am sure that hobby expenses are deductible only to the extent of hobby income and are subject to the 2% of AGI floor for Miscellaneous Expenses: only that part of the total Miscellaneous expenses that exceeds 2% of AGI is deductible. Whether meals and lodging expenses can be deducted at all is another can of worms.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I've updated my answer. Thx for the 2% reminder. I'll have to look into meals and lodging, though my gut says they can be included. Particularly because they give a specific example of the 50% deduction for meals happening before the 2% rule.